# oracle select from 2 table restrict from 1 table and order by another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have book and recipient table.  I want to select maximum 20 rows order by recipient table's membershipdate column. After I got it, i want to order it by book table's id column. I wrote that sql. Is there any way to do this with less code?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    *
          FROM      ( SELECT    b.*
                      FROM      book b
                                JOIN recipient r ON r.id = b.recipient_id
                      WHERE     b.bookno = 115
                      ORDER BY  r.membershipdate DESC
                    )
          WHERE     ROWNUM <= 20
        )
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove one layer of `select`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT    b.*
    FROM      book b
    JOIN recipient r ON r.id = b.recipient_id
    WHERE     b.bookno = 115
    ORDER BY  r.membershipdate DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 20
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Selecting `b.*` isn't normally a good, idea, it's better to specify the columns you actually want, even if you do really want them all - to make sure you get them in the order you expect.

You can also look at the [`row_number()` analytic function in place of `rownum`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm), but that will give you slightly more code - not that it should matter, the effectiveness and efficiency of the query it rather more important that its length.

Comment: @karlkeller - define 'optimum' 8-) You only asked for less code. `row_number()` will be more efficient and easier to work with if you want to do paging I think; if you only ever want the first 20 then either `row_number()` or `rownum` will be about the same. But you should probably test both to confirm. Either way you need two levels of `select` in some form.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

```
                  SELECT * FROM
                   (SELECT    b.*
                    FROM      book b
                            JOIN recipient r ON r.id = b.recipient_id
                    WHERE     b.bookno = 115 ORDER BY  r.membershipdate DESC
                   ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 20
                  ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: No, because rownum is evaluated before the ORDER BY is applied

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can use ROW_NUMBER() function to reduce the code as you want -

and you can even mix your Order columns also.

```
select * from (
select b.*,row_number() over (order by r.membershipdate desc) cnt
from book b
JOIN recipient r ON r.id = b.recipient_id
WHERE b.bookno = 115
order by cnt,b.id desc
) where cnt<=20;
```